# Check timeout errors from net.Listen (tcp) defined by SetReadDeadline

Tags: go

Is there an equivalent method to catch these timeout errors like io.EOF

```
switch err {
case io.EOF:
  //DoSomething, like close connection ...
case net.?:
  //handle timeouts
}
```

Comment: Try the `Timeout()` method on `net.OpError`; something like  `if e, ok := err.(*net.OpError); ok && e.Timeout() { // handle timeout }`.

Comment: Thank you, but any Idea for the switch-statement?

Comment: `*net.OpError` is a type. Use `switch err.(type) {
 case *net.OpError:
  return
 }` but then `io.EOF` will not work since it's not a type.

Comment: Yes, if figured it already out: ying or yang :-)